# Specifying Dense using keras library

Tags: python, keras

I slightly misunderstand how to create a simple Sequence for my data.

The data has the following dimensions:

```
X_train.shape
(2369, 12)

y_train.shape
(2369,)

X_test.shape
(592, 12)

y_test.shape
(592,)
```

This is how I create the model:

```
batch_size = 128
nb_epoch = 20
in_out_neurons = X_train.shape[1] 
dimof_middle = 100

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(batch_size, batch_input_shape=(None, in_out_neurons)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(batch_size))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(in_out_neurons))
model.add(Activation('linear'))

# I am solving the regression problem, not the classification one
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="rmsprop") 

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                    batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
                    verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

The error message:

> Exception: Error when checking model input: expected dense_input_14 to
>   have shape (None, 1) but got array with shape (2369, 12)ç

The error is:

> Error when checking model target: expected activation_42 to have shape
>   (None, 12) but got array with shape (2369, 1)

This error occurs at line:

```
model.add(Dense(in_out_neurons))
```

How to change `Dense` to make it work?

Another question is how to add a simple autoencoder in order to initialize weights of ANN?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of your problems is that you seem to misunderstand what a batch is.
A batch is the number of training samples computed at a time, so instead of computing one training sample from `X_train` at a time you use, for example, 100 at a time. The important bit here is that this has nothing to do with your model.

So when you write

```
model.add(Dense(batch_size, batch_input_shape=(None, in_out_neurons)))
```

then you create a fully connected layer with an output size of one batch. That does not make a lot of sense.

Another problem is that your model's output is 12 neurons while your `Y` is only one value/neuron. Your model looks like this:

```
  |
  v
[128]
[128]
[ 12]
  |
  v
```

Then what `fit()` does is, it inputs a matrix of shape `(128, 12)` (`(batch size, X_train.shape[1])`) into the model and attempts to compare the output of shape `(128,12)` from the last layer to the corresponding `Y` values of the batch (shape `(128,1)`).