# Keras Convolutional Autoencoder: Layer Shapes

Tags: python, keras, autoencoder

I've got a list of about 70,000 training images, each shaped (no. of colour channels, height width) = (3, 30, 30), and about 20,000 testing images. My convolutional autoencoder is defined as:

```
 # Same as the code above, but with some params changed
# Now let's define the model. 

# Set input dimensions:
input_img = Input(shape=(3, 30, 30))

# Encoder: define a chain of Conv2D and MaxPooling2D layers
x = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, 
                  activation='relu', 
                  border_mode='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), border_mode='same')(x)
x = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, 
                  activation='relu', 
                  border_mode='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), border_mode='same')(x)
x = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, 
                  activation='relu', 
                  border_mode='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), border_mode='same')(x)

# at this point, the representation is (8, 4, 4) i.e. 128-dimensional

# Decoder: a stack of Conv2D and UpSampling2D layers
x = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, 
                  activation='relu', 
                  border_mode='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, 
                  activation='relu', 
                  border_mode='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, 
                  activation='relu')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = Convolution2D(1, 3, 3, 
                        activation='sigmoid', 
                        border_mode='same')(x)

autoencoder2 = Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder2.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='mse')
```

Which is the autoencoder from [here](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html).

It throws an error:

```
Error when checking model target: expected convolution2d_14 to have shape (None, 1, 28, 28) but got array with shape (76960, 3, 30, 30)
```

which is weird because I've clearly changed the specified the input shape as (3, 30, 30). Is there some implementation technicality I'm missing?

Comment: Try out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37793144/specifying-dense-using-keras-library

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add border_mode='same' in the last convnet layer of the decoder .

Answer (score 0):

In the https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html, they forgot to add the

`'border_mode='same''`.

For instance, in your 2nd last convolution layer;

`x = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu')(x)`

Answer (score 0):

You should chage the shape of the last convolutional layer from (1,3,3) to (3,3,3) as follows:

```
decoded = Convolution2D(3, 3, 3, 
                    activation='sigmoid', 
                    border_mode='same')(x)
```